# I want to integrate Skype in my iPad application

Tags: ios, sdk, skype

I am new at iPhone developer. I want to integrated Skype in my iPad application, but Developer Skype page reply me:

> "The Skype Developer program is not accepting new registration."

How can I get Skype SDK for integration.  How can I integrated Skype API in my application. Any other way to make developer Skype account. Please help me.

Comment: https://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-ios

Comment: thanks for replying me. I am new at iPhone. Like if some one is not my Skype friend (Skype Contact List). But I want to call him through Skype on their mobile number. Can i get success through above link ?

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation at that link? In particular, see https://developer.skype.com/skype-uris

Answer (score 1):

Skype only allow you to open skype application on your device, if its not installed it opens itunes page for it to download. Oterwise there is no such API available for it.

```
- (IBAction)skypeMe:(id)sender
{
    BOOL installed = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:"]];
    if(installed)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.com/apps/skype/skype"]];
    }
}
```